# What are the differences between various security courses and certificates?

Tags: audit

I have recently taken the CISA exam and am interested in knowing and learning more about IT security. I am not sure where should I start with. I have some programming knowledge with JAVA & SQL, some networking knowledge.

Browsing over the Net, I have found various courses and certificates. However, I could not really identify the differences among them. Would anyone or experienced could help me understand their differences. The following are some courses and certificates I found.

1. AXELOS RESILIA™
2. Cisco Cybersecurity Specialist
3. ISACA Cybersecurity Nexus
4. ISACA CISM

May I know

1. The exams are for whom?
2. Any difference in pursuit of career aspiration as an ethical hacker? Or I should take some other courses and certificates instead?
3. Which one do have a better recognition?

Thanks for resolving my confusions.

Comment: The exams themselves state who they are for. The ones you list are for a spread of topics and professional paths that are not really comparable, and none of them are for ethical hacking.